# Trying to insert a button from php and seeing if a user has clicked it or not however button is not working

Tags: php, html

```
 echo '<form action="query.php" method="POST">';
 echo    '<input style="display: none;" type="text" name="name" value="'.$name.'"> ';
 echo    '<input style="display: none;" type="text" name="password" value="'.$password.'"> ';
 echo    '<input style="display: none;" type="text" name="resume" value="'.$Resume->path.'"> ';
 echo    '<input style="display: none;"  type="text" name="mobile" value="'.$mobile.'"> ';
 echo    '<input style="display: none;" type="text" name="profilePicture" value="'.$profilePicture->path.'"> ';
 echo    '<input style="display: none;" type="text" name="identification" value="'.$identification->path.'"> ';
 echo    '<input style="display: none;" type="text" name="whitecard" value="'.$whitecard->path.'"> ';
 echo    '<input style="display: none;" type="text" name="email" value="'.$email.'"><br> ';
 echo    '<button type="submit" style="">Confirm Register</button>';
 echo    '<input type="button" name="Cancel" id="Cancel" value="Cancel Registration">';
 echo '</form>';
 if(isset($_POST['Cancel'])) {
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'Files/'.$_SESSION['Identification']; unlink($path);
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'Files/'.$_SESSION['Resume']; unlink($path);
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'Files/'.$_SESSION['Whitecard']; unlink($path);
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'Files/'.$_SESSION['Profile']; unlink($path);
   session_unset();
   session_destroy();
  header("Location: http://index.php");
 }
```

I am am trying to get a pre-confirm script running just before my users are inserted into the database so i am trying to generate a button just before they confirm. The confirm button is working however the Cancel appears but is not doing the task it is supposed to do is there a reason why this is not working?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cancel-button doesn't submit the form and if you want to check what's in $_POST you need to have a submitted form.

You could do that manually with Javascript (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp).

Another problem: header() cannot be called after you have printed out something, this will throw you an error.
You cannot do

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['Cancel'])) {
  header('Location: index.php');
}
</body>
</html>
```

You'd have to do

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['Cancel'])) {
  header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I just added another form under where i create the first form in php

Answer (score 1):

An `<input type="button" ..>` does not submit the form. You would use this `type` to cause the button to run some javascript.

To submit the form change it to  `type="submit"`